# How do you get a gwt label to fill a grid cell?

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt label and I place it into a gwt grid. I have some events on the label. So I need the label to fill up the entire grid cell... otherwise the mouse over events won't trigger.

Currently I am doing a setWidth("100%) and setHeight("100%) on the label. This gets the label to fill horizontally... but I can't get the height to fill the grid cell. **How do you get the label to fill the entire grid cell (horz and vert)? isn't there some sort of CSS property I can change to 100%?**

---

The farthest I got was to wrap the label in a grid. Then embed the grid/label into the grid cell. The label then looks like it takes up the entire grid. But the events still only work for the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the event on a cell you could use set a clickhandler on the grid and check if the passed cell in the event is the label cell you need to handle. This way you can certainly have an event that is triggered for the whole cell content.

The reason the cell is not filled 100% is very likely because the table (by default) has cell spacing set, which restricts you from getting a 100% width/height. You can set the cellspacing to 0, but this means it applies to all cells in the table, and that means you layout might change in undesired ways, so having the clickhandler on the table is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

I created a custom "FillLabel" class. Then set the CSS style properties width/height to both be 100%. This custom FillLabel class seems to fulfill the requirements... **Although I feel like there is a more elegant solution and I welcome any others**.

I extended Grid and added the various mouse event interfaces:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.*
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
public class FillLabel 
       extends Grid
       implements HasMouseOutHandlers, 
                  HasMouseOverHandlers,
                  HasMouseMoveHandlers
{

    private Label label;

    /** Use this constructor if you are creating a root for a new tree. */
    public FillLabel(String name) {
        super(1,1);
        this.label = new Label(name);
        this.setWidget(0, 0, this.label);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     * Mouse Over Events
     ***************************************************************************/
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOverHandler(MouseOverHandler handler) {
        return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     * Mouse Out Events
     ***************************************************************************/
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler) {
        return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     * Mouse Move Events
     ***************************************************************************/
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseMoveHandler(MouseMoveHandler handler) {
        return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseMoveEvent.getType());
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a very bad solution, which should not be used.

Comment: When you tell someone "your solution is bad you should do x instead of y to get the same outcome" it's like saying to someone "your solution sucks do it my way but I'm too lazy to say why my way is better... even though it does the same thing" which isn't persuasive at all to me. (you have to contrast your solution x to what is already presented)

Comment: My solution fits all the requirements... so at the very least it is "good" in that "the solution fulfills all the requirements". (... as I already stated I don't think my solution is "elegant".)

Comment: Also at the very least my solution adds value to the discussion of the problem because it offers a different viewpoint.

Comment: Some reasons why it's a bad solution. It's bad because you extend Grid, which means it exposes all the methods on Grid, while it's just a Label. Putting a widget in between because it works, is a workaround for a styling problem which is almost the wrong solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. (I agree that my solution is "a workaround" and that is why in my original answer I said "I feel like there is a more elegant solution".)

Comment: Yes, I should have put the reasons in the initial comment;-)